# Pipewire: autoconnect all audio sources to jack sink (instead of manually doing it with Helvum)

Tags: pipewire

I'm trying to play VR games on my Oculus Quest 2 via Air Link. This is done using a free source code software called ALVR. I was able to connect by headset to this software with no much problems at all, except the audio part.

After some effort, I was able to make it run using a virtual sink created by ALVR with Pipewire. The problem is that this virtual sink is only created when the headset is placed on my head, and it is destroyed when I remove the headset from it. This causes that every time it is destroyed, all audio sources (Steam, Beat Saber, and so on) disconnects from this sink, so when I place again the headset I have to manually reconnect them using the program Helvum. I attached a screenshot of the Helvum program when the headset is connected (audio sink is alsa-jack.jackC.11829). As you can see, 'Beat Saber.exe' isn't connected automatically when the sink is created.

[image: Headset connected (audio sink is alsa-jack.jackC.11829)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helvum is not persistent with connections.
Use qpwgraph.
Make your connections, then click on ''activate'and ''exclusive'' and then - THIS IS IMPORTANT- use the 'patchbay' tab to save .
Qpwgraph should save your set up and connect correctly when sources come and go.

You can either have all the sources you might use running , and then connect them as you wish,and then save, or add each new source as you go  but don't forget to update your saved setup each time a new source is added.

In my experience pipewire is still fickle, so don't be put off if it doesn't work first time. I sometimes save the same setup a couple of times to be sure.
Pipewire usually connects all outputs and inputs, so I find if I dont want all the inputs/outputs I  send the outputs i dont need to an input I dont use :-)

good luck

Comment: I did use Qjackctl and the patchbay. As the name of the headset sink change everytime, I used a regexp to represent the rule. I also had to set the output device on ALVR as jack in order it to work

Answer (score 0):

I see only one way to solve this issue. You can run sh script that picks all outputs by mask and joins it to the specific output.Don't know if it's possible to run the script automatically.

Comment: First answer uses something similar, but already implemented. It is the use of Qjackctl